# Is there a plugin for draggable infobox in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, infobox, balloon-tip

I am displaying a lot of markers with infoboxes and sometimes the infoboxes are overlaps each other. So it there a way to move them? Any plugin or so?Thanks
[image]